# Does Facebook track my application's events even if I disable Facebook Analytics?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have integrated Facebook SDK in my android application. My question is, "Does Facebook know about my app's activity?". I mean, does Facebook know what other parts(code) of my app does? Even if I don't implement Facebook Analytics in it. If yes, how can I make my app's data inaccessible to facebook?

Comment: [It's completely open source](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) you should be able to find out whether or not they are sending parts of your code to their servers ;-)

Comment: Oh, thank you for the reference. But I guess that is a tedious way of finding out:)

Comment: I agree it's a very exhausting process, but I believe, it's the only way to be sure. Note though, that it's highly unlikely for Facebook to even try to do something like this

Comment: Thank you Luca for your opinion.